# how to deal with the dynamic loading of extjs 4 when releasing to server?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, extjs, extjs4.2, sencha-cmd

I often use the `Ext.require()` functionality of Extjs which lets the it dynamically load the specific content.

But the documentation specifies that when released to the production environment, the dynamic loading feature should never be used. So how can I deal with so many `Ext.requires()` in my code? The official doc said that the sencha cmd could solve this problem if you follow the scaffolding. But I didn't know about the sencha cmd when I wrote the code.

So, how should I update my code?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to merge all your JS files into a production build (taking care of ExtJS requirements) is to use SenchaCMD.

If you didn't follow CMD practices during development it could be quite hard. Fortunately your JS source code will not be changed, you must only be sure to have defined "requires" attribute correctly instead of using Ext.requires (otherwise it would continue to use dynamic loading...).

It really depends on you project structure and you coding style, but steps are:

- Download Sencha CMD (last version)
- Create a fresh Sencha app with "sencha generate app"
- Add your application start logic in the "launch" method of Application.js (consider adding also all your missing requirements in this class)
- Add all your source files in the app folder and try to run "sencha app build" (better if you add a subset of your app, try to build it, eventually fix it, the add another part).
- Now you should have 2 new builds: "production build" is a single file minified JS, "testing build" is single file non mified. There is also a "development mode" of sencha CMD that starts a Tomcat server and deploy you application as you are doing now.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent reply. I wonder why we could not use the dynamic loading in the production environment?  I think it is useful in the production level, which means you could just load the required js file at a time. For example, I have 2 js files(views) which will be loaded conditionally, if the login user is A, the A.js will be loaded instead of B. so, my code could be as follows: if(loginName === A){ Ext.require("A");}else{Ext.require("B")}. So, how the sencha cmd will handle this situation?

Comment: In addition, I am  using the asp.net mvc as the backend framework. The main entry of the html file will be Index.cshtml which is located in the Views folder created by the mvc framework's scaffolding mechanism. I wanna put the js files inside another folder to make the code more nicely structured. So, when using the shencha cmd, how to deal with this? Thank you!

Comment: The point, I think, is performance. Even if you manage what to load or not with dynamic loading, it's always better to load JS source code with a single heavy call to server rather than a huge number of small requests (extjs class structure drives you to write hundreds of files). An initial single load permit also to execute all the classes definitions so there will be less work during app usage.

Comment: Another good point is code minification/obfuscation that comes with sencha cmd (YUI compressor), you could do it obviously without sencha cmd but thare are some good optimizations for the framework. Anyway there are also advantages to work with a "normal" deploy of your app using dynamic loading, first of all, sencha cmd is really strict about project structure! My suggestion is, if yuo want sencha cmd, follow ALL of its best practices and do not try to modify much of its provided builds :P